# Model binding with jquery ajax serialize not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have the following model:

```
public class RegisterUseraccount
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "E-Mail-Adresse")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Vorname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nachname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [MinLength(5)]
    [Display(Name = "Passwort")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And the following view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Useraccount", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "registerUseraccountForm", @class = "ym-form" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)        

    <div class="ym-grid">
        <div class="ym-g50 ym-gl">
            <div class="ym-fbox-text">
                @Html.LabelForRequired(model => model.RegisterUseraccount.FirstName, null)               
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterUseraccount.FirstName, new { required = "required", name = "firstName" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegisterUseraccount.FirstName)                  
            </div>
        </div>
    ...
```

and my JavaScript

```
function sendForm(target) {
    alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: $("#registerUseraccountForm").serialize(),
        success: ajaxOnSuccess,
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            alert('Error message.');
        }
    });
```

This is the result of the serialization:

```
RegisterUseraccount.FirstName=Peter&RegisterUseraccount.LastName=Miller&RegisterUseraccount.Email=miller%40gmail.com&RegisterUseraccount.Password=admin
```

This is my controller method I'm trying to POST to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterUseraccount registerUseraccount)
{
    ...
}
```

... but the data doesn't arrive at the method, I get an error 404. I think the modelbinder can't work.

What works is data which is sent with the name firstName=Peter, but what actually is sent is RegisterUseraccount.FirstName=Peter.

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the `url` is correct?

Comment: Where are you calling `sendForm` method ?

Comment: remove `contentType: 'application/json',`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

remove `contentType: 'application/json',` and modify it to better (from my perspective)

```
$('#registerUseraccountForm').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            complete: function () {

            },
            ...
```

Comment: You were right, all I had to do was to remove the contentType ... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have this model

```
public class YourModel
{
    public RegisterUseraccount RegisterUseraccount { get; set; }
}
```

In this case you have to put the model that corresponds to your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(YourModel model)
{
    var registerUseraccount = model.RegisterUseraccount;
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Useraccount", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "registerUseraccountForm", @class = "ym-form" }))
{
   @{ Html.RenderPartial("RegisterUseraccount"); }
}
```

RegisterUseraccount.cshtml

```
@model YourNamespace.RegisterUseraccount

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)        

<div class="ym-grid">
    <div class="ym-g50 ym-gl">
        <div class="ym-fbox-text">
            @Html.LabelForRequired(model => model.FirstName, null)               
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { required = "required", name = "firstName" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)                  
        </div>
    </div>
```

but you'll have to change some things like `@Html.ValidationSummary (true)`.

**Edit**

or most simple:

```
data: $("#registerUseraccountForm").serialize().replace("RegisterUseraccount.",""),
```

**Edit II**

```
data: $("#registerUseraccountForm").serialize().replace(/RegisterUseraccount./g,""),
```

Comment: .replace() only replaces the first instance of the string, so it's not working.

Comment: This has worked:
var data = $("#registerUseraccountForm").serialize().replace(new RegExp("RegisterUseraccount.", "g"), '');

Comment: @mosquito87 thanks for the comments, I already fix the javascript code

Answer (score 0):

There are two variations of posting data with jQuery ajax.

1. Use $.ajax
2. Use $.post

Below shows how to use  $.post

```
   $('#btn-register').click(function () {

        var $form = $('#registerUseraccountForm');

         if ($form.valid()) {
        
               var url = $form.attr('action'),
                   fd = $form.serialize();
    
                $.post(url, fd).done(function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Success!',
                            'User registered successfully',
                            'success'
                        )
                    } else
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Failed!',
                            'Failed to register user',
                            'error'
                        )
                }).fail(function () {
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Failed!',
                        'Failed to register user',
                        'error'
                    )
                });
            }else{
                Swal.fire(
                    'Invalid!',
                    'Form contains invalid data',
                    'error'
                )
            }
        });
```

I would say in such places where you don't require to do additional configurations as you do with $.ajax, simply serialize the form and just post. Of course, validate the form if you already defined validations for fields. Pretty straightforward!

Comment: FYI : Here "Swal"  is a separate javascript lib called 'Sweet alerts'