# ASP.Net MVC model binding to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The question is pretty straightforward: I use `@Html.EditorForModel()` to generate fields for my model. Then user fills all these fields and I want to send this field via `AJAX`, becuase I should do several server's services without page reload.

I googled several approaches, but it seems that there is no standard way to do such things. I mean I do not have an object on client-side that represent model. I found one single library calls `JSModel` ([link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jsmodel/)) but it seems to be not working. My code for now is:

```
@model Student

<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.12.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript" async="async"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/Requester.js")" type="text/javascript" async="async"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jsmodel.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var requester = new Requester(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new Student())));

    function SendSignupRequest() {
        requester.SendSignupRequest();
    }
</script>

<h2>Student</h2>
<div>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
</div>
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="SendSignupRequest()"/>
```

Requester.js:

```
function Requester(rawModel) {
    this.modelObj = new JSModel(rawModel);

    this.SendSignupRequest = function() {
        var model = modelObj.refresh();
        var val = model.prop("Name");
        alert(val);
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way to serialize a model object in JSON and send it to server, without manually constructing an object with millions of `document.getElementById`?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717715/model-binding-with-jquery-ajax-serialize-not-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-compact ", role = "form", id = "form1" }))
    {

    }
```

Java Script

```
var formdata = $("#form1").serializeArray();

$.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formdata,
                success: function (data) {
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult action(Model model)
{
//access data here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, it is most suitable in my case. Enchanced code could be found in this [url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor).

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize your form to a JSON object with jQuery:

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
```

(This would, of course, mean wrapping your form elements in a `form`, which really should be happening anyway.)

Then just pass that `data` object to the server in the POST request.  Something as simple as:

```
$.post('some/url', data, function(response) {
    // success callback
});
```

> without manually constructing an object with millions of document.getElementById

Note that if your object has *millions* of fields then you may very well encounter *other* problems here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes you can use form serialize using Jquery

 var formData = $('#form').serializeObject();
  $.extend(formData, { Contacts : myContacts});
  $.extend(formData, { Address : myAddress});
  var result = JSON.stringify(formData);

  $('#formHiddenField').val(result);

  then submit form using:
      $.ajax(
     url: @Url.Action("post url")
     data: myForm.serialize(),
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(){
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not `Ajax.BeginForm()` for your purposes. I believe model binding works automatically.